# Database connectivity in php and html

Tags: php, html, database

I have some doubts about connecting the database

- how do i connect the PHP file with database(php my admin)?
- what code should i give to check the correct and incorrect passwords?
- how do i connect the database with my html page?

Actually i had tried a lot of programs to connect them, But in vain.
I have completed the layouts. Just the database connectivity is pending.

[image: this is the code i have done.Please see the image]

Comment: check error logs and debug

Comment: post real code and not an image of it, that does not help anyone, including yourself

Answer (score -3):

You must first make an acc on phpmyadmin and the connection shoul be like this:

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost","yourusername","yourpass","the database u want to work on");
```

This is the connection to a db.
I think u dont know php and thats why are u asking. U better learn and read about this. Check www.w3schools.com for php lessons.

Comment: thanks....but i have tried all these what you said but still database is not connected and i have completed my php course still im not able to get the database connected